# Android layout doesn't load in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin for developing android application. I want to switch to Visual Studio(2013) because is more familiar to me, but I have a problem when I try to edit layouts. The designer doesn't load at all, I view just an empty rectangle on the layout, even if in code the xml is present with all elements.
What I'm doing wrong? I should connect visual studio with Android Designer? 
Thank you in advance!
Images of layouts - design and xml (I cannot add them here :| )
1. Designer - http://imgur.com/B0u5XaC,pGMJuky#0
2. XML - http://imgur.com/B0u5XaC,pGMJuky#1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. I'll post the solution, maybe it can help others - the problem was related to sdk v.23.0.5. I downgrade it to 23.0.3 and now it works perfectly!